# How to shorten a link using bitly API that contains a url in GET parameters [PHP]

Tags: php, get

I am trying to shorten a url using the PHP API from bitly. The url I am trying to shorten contains a url in the GET parameters.

The url is similar to

`http://www.my.domain.io/Embed.php?k=318353564&p=something&a=someone&d=true&i=http://i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg&pop=true&popn=0`

When I use a version of the link in which `i` has been `urlencode()` first, the returned shortened link sends me to is `http://www.my.domain.io/Embed.php?k=318353564` the remaining parameters are cut off.

When I use `urlencode()` on the entire link after `urlencode()` the parameter `i` it returns the whole link `http://www.my.domain.io/Embed.php?k=318353564&p=something&a=someone&d=true&i=http://i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg&pop=true&popn=0` but because the parameter `i` is not encoded in the link it just gives me a 403 error.

When I send the link with no encoding at all it returns the link without parameters again. When I send the link with `urlencode()` on the entire link it returns the literal version of the link again resulting in a 403 error. So that's 4 different ways of trying to encode the link none of which lead me to the correct link.

Comment: Not really an answer, but can't you remove the http:// from the suburl? have it like `i=i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg` or `is=i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg` for https, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "%26" instead of ampersand (&).

```
http://www.my.domain.io/Embed.php?k=318353564%26p=something%26a=someone%26d=true%26i=http://i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg%26pop=true
```

When I query bitly API with the following GET parameters:

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/shorten?version=2.0.1&login=<bitly_username>&access_token=<bitly_accesstoken>&format=json&history=1&longUrl=http://www.my.domain.io/Embed.php?k=318353564%26p=something%26a=someone%26d=true%26i=http://i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg%26pop=true
```

I get a link such as http://bit.ly/1n4OuzX, which redirect me to your original URL.

Update:
When I change the domain from "www.my.domain.io" to my local web server it sends the parameters to it fine.

Here is a print_r:

```
Array
(
    [k] => 318353564
    [p] => something
    [a] => someone
    [d] => true
    [i] => http://i.imgur.com/gBlh6Zm.jpg
    [pop] => true
    [popn] => 0
)
```

Comment: that does bring me to the literal url but im still getting a 403 error. If I go to the same url without the 'i' parameter everything works fine. I think it's because the slashes in the image link are not encoded. My problem is that I can not figure out how to encode them.

Comment: I updated original answer with dump. Maybe I am missing something here.